# What is wrong with my PyODBC? I am getting a backend.py error. When i step into this code I get a code "Backend terminated (returncode: 6)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, thonny

Whenever I try to run this or step into this i am getting this code. I am very new to python and barely know the language, but I was trying to get this code to connect to an SQL and was hoping for any hope syntax wise or even trying another approach. Anything is greatly appreciated.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};Server={********};Port=1433;Database=****;Trusted_Connection=yes;TDS_Version=7.2;')


Current thread 0x76fac010 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/pi/NData_GrabS8.py", line 42 in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 588 in execute_source
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 427 in _execute_source_ex
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 374 in _execute_file
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 155 in _cmd_Run
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 119 in handle_command
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 97 in mainloop
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/backend_launcher.py", line 41 in <module>
Resetting ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the server that i was trying to get into only used a windows authentication and the raspberry pi that i was using did not have this access to login. Instead I had to make a login for the pi alone. The trusted_connection was where it was failing and after I took that out the user id and password connected to it on the first try. If this answer was not clear enough please just comment and I will do my best to elaborate.